# Primality test in GPG/RSA or extract numbers of private key

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, pgp

I cannot find if the two numbers for RSA are tested against an [elliptic curve primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_primality_proving). If not, is there a way to extract the two integers of my private key in order to test it by myself?

If this is not an accurate question why?

Comment: In what format does whatever-you're-using store the private key? ​ ​

Comment: I am using GPG, so the only thing I can say is, I can export the private key that contains those prime numbers.

Answer (score 3):

GPG (1.4.21) does not use an elliptic curve primality test. It uses 5 [strong pseudoprime tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_pseudoprime), with the first to base 2 and the others to a random base. For factors large enough that the key is secure, odds that a composite creep by chance are entirely negligible in practice (for a quantitative estimate see [appendix F.1 in FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=126)). Also, the mere fact that an RSA key allows decryption of messages, or generation of signatures that verify, is a fair probabilistic primality test of its factors.

To dump a private key not protected by a passphrase under gpg 1.4.x, use
`gpg --export-secret-key -a "john doe" | gpg --list-packets --debug 2`

For a key version 4 algo 1, the factors of the public modulus are `skey[3]` and `skey[4]`.